# relative path in res:// in resource files

Tags: winapi, internet-explorer, resources

I use in my win32 application embedded IE (IWebBrowser2)
And I load resources from resorces by res:// protocol

My .res file looks like

```
index.html HTML "index.html"
foo.js     HTML "foo.js"
```

And it works.

But I need add resource with relative path, something like

?     HTML "img\logo.jpg"

Is it possible to add such resource? And how?

In my index.html I user code like

> `<img src="img/logo.jpg">`

Comment: Relative URLs should work just fine; they're what IE itself uses internally for its resource pages. Are you encountering a problem that goes away if you specify a fully-qualified path?

Comment: i solve trouble with   logo.jpg img "img/logo.jpg"